# Specify source in nuspec dependency

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I have a local **NuGet** feed. This feed contains a dependency and that dependency is on nuget.org.

This is in my nuspec file:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="log4net" version="[1.2.10]" />
</dependencies>
```

How can I specify that NuGet has to look in nuget.org for this dependency? I currently receive:

> Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'log4net (= 1.2.10)'.

When I perform an Install-Package via the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you using visual studio?

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using the Package Manager Console to perform Install-Package on my project. My nuspec file just points to another dependency that is not on the same feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but specifying the `-Source` parameter during install seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In your Package manager console, the top left corner has a dropdown to select the package source. Make sure you have selected "All" when you try to install packages that might have dependencies from other package sources.